# Brokering Investment on F-1 OPT

Tags: usa, student-visa, working

I am F-1 US Visa-holding student with OPT authorization that is good May 9th through August 15th.

I have an opportunity to broker an investment in a manufacturing company registered in Nevada, USA. Am I eligible to claim brokerage on such an effort? Or does my F-1 visa prevent me from collecting such compensation?

Comment: DHS has a new resource https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/ , would recommend going through the site or posting a question for them over there